# Kryo deserializer throws ClassNotFoundException in spark: Unable to find class

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, kryo

I am writing a spark job in scala to be run with spark 1.3.0. My RDD transformation functions use classes from a third party library which are not Serializable. To make closure serialization possible, I wrap these objects in com.twitter.chill.MeatLocker which is itself java.io.Serializable but uses Kryo for the wrapped objects. Then I make an uber jar using assembly.

When I run my job, the executors tasks fail throwing a ClassNotFoundException for the same classes that I wrapped inside MeatLocker. I know that there was a related bug in spark 1.2.x but googling on this subject suggests me that it has been fixed in 1.3.0. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6069

I have tried spark configuration property spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true but to no effect. I passed this property to spark-submit script like so:
`spark-submit --class <My-Class> <My-Jar> --conf spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true`

Beyond this I am stuck with no option but to get the source of the third party library and include it in my project after making these classes implement java.io.Serializable. That way I will eliminate the need for Kryo serialization altogether thereby not running into this issue but I hope for a better way.

Comment: Did you solve your problem since then ?